# faster way for moving large amounts data in oracle to external database

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I have a java program that compares and moves data from a local Oracle database to an external MS SQL data base hosted by an online vendor.

Currently the program connects to the MS SQL database doing a `SELECT * FROM myTABLE` and putting the results in a two-dimensional array.  A temp table is then created in Oracle and the data is inserted into the temp table using a for loop:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < arr.length(); ii++){
    query = "insert into myTable_temp values "+values_from_array;
    stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

A `MINUS` statement is used find the differences:

```
query = "select * from ora_table minus select * from myTable_temp";
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

and the result is then inserted back into the MS SQL table using a insert_into_mssql() method:

```
while (rs.next()){
    query = "insert into myTable values "+ values_from_rs
    insert_into_mssql(query);
}
```

This works fine except a table I am using has 220,000 rows.  So it takes a long time to load the array, insert into temp table, run the minus statement, then insert everything back into the mssql table.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? or a way to make this faster?
(a dblink or any direct connection wont work bc of security restrictions)

Comment: Has your organization really thought about these security restrictions?  A database link requires only one extra set of privileges, and encrypts your passwords.  Did you create an extra account on a different server for this Java program, and grant it rights to both databases?  Are the passwords encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, What version of MS SQL Server are you using? Depending on that, you can look into [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) or other [DTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx) software. It allows you to do excactly what you want very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to create a [dblink](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it may help you.

The new addBatch( ) method of Statement allows you to lump multiple update statements as a unit and execute them at once. Call addBatch( ) after you create the statement, and before execution:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false); // If some fail, we want to rollback the rest
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(  );

stmt.addBatch(
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (1, "J Smith", "617 555-1323");
stmt.addBatch(
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (2, "A Smith", "617 555-1132");
stmt.addBatch(
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (3, "C Smith", "617 555-1238");
stmt.addBatch(
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (4, "K Smith", "617 555-7823");

int[] upCounts = stmt.executeBatch(  );
con.commit(  );
```

Notice that we turn transaction auto-commit off before creating the batch.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe start by not loading it into an array and just using a similar technique as is used in your writing out.  Could also look at parallelizing the inserts.

If I was doing this from scratch, I would bring all the Oracle data to SQL Server and do everything there (copy table from Oracle, find differences and insert into SQL Server, drop the table copied from Oracle) instead of bringing all the SQL Server data to Oracle, dumping just the new records and bringing them over to SQL Server and inserting them.

SQL Server also has a pretty good ETL tool - SQL Server Integration Services, but I haven't had a lot of success using it with things besides SQL Server data sources and destinations.

Comment: I have used SSIS migrating data from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database with no trouble. Actually when it comes to sources and destinations, SSIS works great with almost anything (DBs, Excel files, flat files, you name it)

Comment: @Cade Roux How would you bring all the Oracle data to the SQL Server?

Comment: @Mike You could do it the same way you do just the changed records now, but I would use SSIS.

Comment: @AJC I had problems using it with Teradata.  Excel and Access are problematic on 64-bit environments.  But yes, it is generally pretty awesome.

Comment: @Mike SSIS allows you to connect to any source, Extract the data, Transform it, and then Load it into any destination, hence ETL.

Comment: @Cade I haven't tried Teradata, but excel for me has worked great. It does have some issues regarding column placement and naming, but the way it lets you query the spreadsheet as if it were a DB is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account technological limitations (no dblinks and so on) you can try to lower transport overhead.
This can be done by maintaining synchronization state and transferring only updated rows.

If I understand correctly, you need only transfer updated and new rows from Oracle database to MS SQL. In very generic variant you need to add 2 columns into `oracle_table` which holds replication state:

`last_update_time` - maintained by trigger on insert or update for each row. Trigger set column value to current date and time on each row change and for new row.

`last_sync_time` - maintained by trigger on insert and changed by sync application.

For new row `last_update_time := sysdate` and `last_sync_time := last_update_time - 1`.

On each `oracle_table` row update `last_update_time` updated by current date time.

On each synchronization session next sequence performed:

1. Select all rows from `oracle_table` where `last_sync_time < last_update_time` and insert it to some buffer table on Oracle server:

   ```
   begin
     execute immediate 'truncate table buffer_table';

     insert into buffer_table(...)
     select * from oracle_table where last_sync_time < last_update_time;

   end;
   ```
2. Transfer all rows from buffer_table to MS SQL server and update `myTable` accordingly.
3. Advance update time for all synchronized rows to new value:

   ```
   update 
     oracle_table o_table
   set 
     last_sync_time = ( select buf_table.last_update_time 
                        from buffer_table buf_table
                        where buf_table.Primary_Key = o_table.Primary_Key
                      )
   where
     o_table.Primary_Key in (select Primary_Key from buffer_table)
   ```

Note that synchronized rows may be changed during synchronization process and we need timestamp value from `buffer_table` while updating `last_sync_time`.

*P.S. I supposed that database on MS SQL side is read-only. Two-way synchronization can be done on the same principle with slightly algorithm improvements.*